# Bullet Physics Library not Found

Tags: c++, build, cmake, bulletphysics

I am attempting to compile a git repository that requires Bullet Physics as a dependency. When I attempt to compile it, I receive the following error while running cmake:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
  Could NOT find Bullet (missing: BULLET_DYNAMICS_LIBRARY_DEBUG
  BULLET_COLLISION_LIBRARY_DEBUG BULLET_MATH_LIBRARY_DEBUG
  BULLET_SOFTBODY_LIBRARY_DEBUG)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:374 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake_modules/FindBullet.cmake:74 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:124 (find_package)
```

The exact sequence of commands that leads to this error:

```
~/Thrive$ mkdir build
~/Thrive$ cd build
~/Thrive/build$ cmake ..
```

This error persists even though I have Bullet installed. How can I resolve  this?

---

### Details:

- OS: Ubuntu 15.10 (wily)
- Architecture: AMD64
- Bullet Version: 2.83

  - Include Directory: `/usr/include/bullet`
- cmake Version: 3.2
- Repository: [Thrive](https://github.com/Revolutionary-Games/Thrive)

  - Language: C++

Comment: According to [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBullet.html), you may try to set `BULLET_ROOT` variable to installation directory of Bullet.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I tried running `export BULLET_ROOT=/usr/include/bullet/` prior to running the `cmake` command without any luck. A few other `BULLET_ROOT` paths I tested gave identical results.

Comment: You should get some basic knowledge with CMake! You have to call `cmake -DBULLET_ROOT=<your path>`

Comment: @usr1234567 I had tried that as well with no results. I'm thinking that the path I'm using is wrong.

Comment: `BULLET_ROOT` should point to the **root of the whole package**, not to the include directory. Try `/usr` value for it. (Assuming there are Bullet library files under `/usr/lib`). If this doesn't help, add to your post actual paths of Bullet's include directory and library one.

Comment: Maybe you have to delete your CMakeCache.txt file?